# Let $f(x,y)$ be a function of two variables such that $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}=5$. Which is true?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function of two variables such that $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}=5$

Which is true?

(*a*) We have $f(0,0)=5$

(*b*) If $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ but not reaching $(0,0)$, then $f(x,y)$ approaches $5$ but not reaching $5.$

(*c*) If $(x,y)$ approaches and reaches $(0,0)$, then $f(x,y)$ approaches and reaches $5$

(*d*) None of them are true.

My solution

> For (*b*), this seems to be true as this is essentially the definition of limits, isn't it? As $x$ reaches $0,$ y reaches $0,$ but not at $(0,0)$, $f(x,y)$ reaches $5$, but not at $5$ exactly.

But my answer says otherwise..

Please enlighten and thanks!

Comment: $f(x,y) = 5$ is a function which is at exactly 5 all the time as well as has $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow 0} = 5$. I would say (d) is the correct answer.

Comment: (b) [...] $f(x,y)$ approaches 5 but NOT REACHING (<- false) 5.

Comment: so f(x,y) actually reaches 5? That is not what i remember actually.. Say we are not talking about the example that musically gives, but a general example.

Comment: Ok nvm I think I understand perfectly now thanks a lot music and ricky.

Comment: One specific example is enough to show that b is not always true! $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}=5$$ is simply not sufficient to decide whether or not $$f(x,y)=5$$ for some point other than the origin.

Comment: Can someone list an answer instead of commenting? XD. I want to give the rep and close this haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all false.

a) and c) Let f(x) =
$\begin{cases}
5, & \text {if (x,y)} \neq \text{(0,0)} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

b) $f(x,y) = 5$

Comment: not they are not, d) is true

Answer (score -2):

a) false because there could be a discontinuity

b) false because $f(x,y)$ could be equal to $5$ on the entire interval approaching it.  In that case "but not reaching it" disqualifies this choice.

c) True. The hypothesis says that $f(x,y)$ approaches $5$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $0$.  Since choice c lets $(x,y)$ reach its limit, $f(x,y)$ reaches $5$.

Comment: No this is incorrect. The function $f(x,y)=5$ except at $(0,0)$ where it equals $f(0,0)=0$ is a counterexample.